# Error when plugging iPod Touch into MacBook

Tags: 10.10, ipod, macbook

Whenever I plug my iPod Touch (2nd gen) into my MacBook running Ubuntu 10.10 I get the following error:

> DBus error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)

It will show up in the file browser but whenever I try to mount it I get that error.

**EDIT**: I thought that this might be because I had it plugged into a dock, but I tried plugging it in directly to the MacBook with the USB Cable and it still does not work, same error message.

Comment: I get this same error. Are you running iOS 4.2.1 on your iPod touch? If so, that's the issue. Apple changed something inbetween 4.1 and 4.2.1.

Comment: Yeah, I am running 4.2.1, so does that make this unsolvable?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, it seems that since I am running 4.2.1, it just isn't possible.

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pmcenery/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

i did it yesterday, and worked flawlessly for me (4.2.1 iOS)

Comment: HELL YES! The above post fixed my issue! iPod touch 4.2.1 :-) THANK YOU

Comment: you're welcome :) by the way, could you mark my answer as the right  one? thanks!

Comment: +1, that worked! On an iPhone 4, version 4.2.1. Took a long time to process those three commands though (around 10 minutes).

Comment: It worked for me too; you should really consider marking this answer as accepted!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same problem mounting my iPAd running iOS 4.2.1.
I run Ubuntu desktop 10.10.
If anyone has a solution that would be nice.

My next solution is to run windows 7 in Virtual Box, then install iTunes. I REALLY wish that there were an itunes build for Ubuntu. I tried running Wine and then installing iTunes. Never could get it to work.

///Update

I just followed the instructions in this link: http://www.webupd8.org/2010/12/get-ios4-mountsync-working-in-ubuntu.html

I now am able to mount my iPad!

Comment: This isn't an answer. Post as a separate question, otherwise it won't be possible to answer your question.

Comment: Keith's solution (Dec 30 '10) worked for me as well.  Thanks, Keith!

Answer (score -1):

Follow this post, it does the trick:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10205459&postcount=32